# What is wrong with this if function based on iFrame selector?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to hide an iframe w/ the class of cs-iframe if it is on a certain URL by creating an if statement with the  src URL

Right now, the selection part is not working with the if statement.

```
var theiFrame = document.getElementByClass("cs-iframe");

function hideiFrame() {
      if (theiFrame.src = "http://www.test.com") {
        alert("successful selection");
      };
};
```

Thank you Sunday Stack Gods

Comment: [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) or you can use query selector [Element.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector) if you want to get first element with class *cs-iframe*

Comment: Have you looked for error messages in your JS console?

Answer (score 2):

The function is named `document.getElementByClassName`. It does not return a single element, but an array of elements.

Then, in your if condition, you do `theiFrame.src = "http://www.test.com"`. With a single equal sign, this is an assignment expression, just like on the first line of your code. To check if two values are equal, you should use `==` or `===` (to see why there are two operators, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)).

Finally, you could do this entirely in CSS, by using an attribute selector:

```
iframe[src="http://www.test.com"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: CSS won't work for this scenario because the iframe adds additional values to the end of the source upon load, so that the iframe src in the HTML page originally is not the same in the DOM.

src="http://test.com/orginal-url?&ampadditioal-values-added"

I would use * but I don't want to hide every frame of this iFrame.

Sorry this wasn't clarified earlier

Comment: No worries. If the src attribute always starts with test.com, you can still do: `iframe[src^="http://www.test.com"]`, which will select all iframes where src _starts_ with this value. [Here is the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).